# в таблицу заносится только первая строка в файле php

Tags: php, mysql

Есть задача.
Разработать проект, обеспечивающий перевод информации из текстового файла data.txt в таблицу people базы данных по нажатию кнопки. В текстовом файле хранится произвольный объем информации и людях (фамилия, идентификационный номер, город рождения)

Структура таблицы people
Наименование поля   Тип поля    Хранимая информация Ключевое поле
Id_people   Целое (счетчик) Код человека    *
Name_people Строка (100)    Фамилия человека
Number_people   Целое   Идентификационный номер человека
City_people Строка (100)    Город рождения

Проблема в том. что в таблицу заносится только первая строка, а вторая не заносится. Прошу помощи разобраться. Структура файла и код представлены ниже.

iwanoff 123 kharkiv

sidorow 345 lviv

```
   <?php

  if (isset($_GET['button'])){
 $db=mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("don't connet with 
   MySQL.");
    mysql_select_db("exam", $db) or die("don't connet with db.");
    $file = 'data.txt';     
    $f = fopen($file,"r") or die ("file is not exist");
    $a = array();
    while (($data = fgets($f))!==false){
        $a0 = explode(" ",$data);
        foreach($a0 as $item)
            $a[] = $item;
    }
    fclose($f);

     for ($i = 0;$i < count($a); $i++){
            $sql="INSERT INTO `result5`(`name_p`, `number`, `city`) VALUES 
    ('$a[0]','$a[1]','$a[2]')";
            mysql_query($sql);      
            echo $a[$i]." ";
   }
   if (mysql_errno()==0)
        echo " ok";
    else
    echo " not ok: " . mysql_error() . "\n";
  }
```

Comment: `($data = fgets($f))!==false)`  ошибка `($data = fgets($f))!=false)`

Comment: спасибо за подсказку. исправила, но результат не изменился.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $file = 'data.txt';   
// Игнорить \n и пропустить пустые строки 
$f = file('data.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES) or die ("file is not exist");
$a = array();

foreach($f as $line_num => $line){// Проходит по каждой строчке
    $a = explode(" ",$line);

        $sql="INSERT INTO `result5`(`name_p`, `number`, `city`) VALUES 
('$a[0]','$a[1]','$a[2]')";
        mysql_query($sql);      
        echo $a[$i]." ";
}
```

Comment: сейчас попробую

Answer (score 0):

Упрощённый вариант:

```
$file = file('source.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES) or die ("File is not exists.");

foreach($file as $line_num => $line)
{
    $array = explode(" ", $line);
    if (count($array) != 3)
        continue;

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO result5 (name_p, number, city) VALUES ('{$array[0]}','{$array[1]}','{$array[2]}')");
    echo "Name: " . $array[0] . ", Number: " . $array[1] . ", City: " . $array[2] . "\n";
}
```